# Adding Comments in CMake command line to bypass unnecessary arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, makefile, cmake

I found an issue with a CMake tool I'm currently using and I am looking for a workaround,

The tool I am using is VisualGDB, the problem is that the CMake command it executes appends some unneeded information.

It has an option to add arguments to the cmake command, but it places those arguments to the beginning of the command, instead of the end.

For a more detailed explanationand the bug report, please see this post
https://sysprogs.com/w/forums/topic/bug-submission-possible-feature-improvement/#post-6786

This question is not related to that post however, 
All I am looking for it a way to enter my commands into the cmake command line and comment out the commands provided by the tool.

For example, for arguments I would enter:

```
 -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../armtoolchain-vs.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/make.exe" ../source #
```

Or

```
 -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../armtoolchain-vs.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/make.exe" ../source REM
```

So that the final command is:

```
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../armtoolchain-vs.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/make.exe" ../source # -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain-Debug.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/make.exe"" in directory "D:\svn\Project\source/../vs_arm_debug/" on local computer
```

Where the # or the REM arguments case the rest of the command line to be ignored.

However, when I use either of these, it doesn't seem to work, this is the error I get:

```
EXEC : CMake error : The source directory "D:/svn/Project" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

To explain, the command steps back with .. and tries to look for CMakeLists in the root project directory, not in the source directory,

Even if I just use REM or # for arguments, te program still presents me with the same error, meanign that it is not ignoring those oterh arguments after # or REM.

My question is, what can I inject into the argument line to make cmake ignore the following parameters?

The cmake line is part of the build script for VS and if if it doesn't successfully runt he project won't build. So unfortuantely, I have to use this tool and I cannot run cmake independently.

I may be able to make a came.bat file and link to it, including the commands inside

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to create a Cmake.bin file in the same directory as cmake.exe, and enter into it:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../armtoolchain-vs.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/make.exe" ../source
echo
```

This would make the unwanted arguments go into the echo line instead of the cmake line